# How to show proper time in Ubuntu Software Centre history

Tags: software-center

There were some occasions when I needed to know the time I installed or uninstalled something from the Ubuntu Software Centre so that I can diagnose some problem. It is great that the time is shown under `history` there, even up to the second. However the am/pm is not shown and the time is not given in the 24-hour clock format. Is there a way to configure it to show the am/pm or 24-hour clock?

Update: The am/pm is now shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature is not available at this time, you can file a feature request using a bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center

Please note that the historical is retrieved from a text file log which you can read with your prefered text editor:

```
/var/log/dpkg.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Have not looked at the file yet, but you maybe able to write a simple shell script that converts the format in the log file.